Outlook changes the "Modified" field when moving/copying a Contact
I use Outlook 2021.
When I copy/move a Contact item from one Contacts folder to another Contacts folder, the "Modified" field gets updated to the current date. I don't modify the Contact itself... I only move it or copy it.
Is there a way to keep the "Modified" field unchanged?
Thank you for your help,
Martin

Do you mean the below column?

If so, i'm afraid that it's by design when you move/copy a contact.

Yep, that exact field...
